# .config not getting updated after modification to tegra3_android_defconfig

Tags: kernel, android-kernel

.config not getting updated after modification to tegra3_android_defconfig After adding a module(MODULE_XX_CONFIG=y) inside tegra3_android_defconfig, I did "make tegra3_android_defconfig" though the build is successful, the generated .config doesn't have the newly added entry.

Answer (score 1):

**Caution** :: This answer is for standard Linux kernel. I'm not sure about android-kernel.

Adding configuration flag only to `tegra3_android_defconfig` is not enough. Same configuration should be included in Kconfig file also.

When defconfig is done, .config will be generated based on Kconfig files. Only value for that particular configuration is taken from arch/XX/configs/XX_defconfig.

If value for particular configuration is not mentioned in XX_defconfig, then the default value mentioned in Kconfig will be used and the .config file will be generated.

Consider `CONFIG_IPV6` flag in [tegra_defconfig](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/configs/tegra_defconfig?v=3.11#L58) of standard kernel.

The following file is responsible for that configuration.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv6/Kconfig

```
IPV6                ---> CONFIG_IPV6 
IPV6_OPTIMISTIC_DAD ---> CONFIG_IPV6_OPTIMISTIC_DAD
IPV6_ROUTER_PREF    ---> CONFIG_IPV6_ROUTER_PREF
```

Comment: My Kconfig is proper but I forgot to add ---> source "drivers/xxx/Kconfig" inside the root Kconfig file to allow the build to use my Kconfig.

Comment: Thanks for replying !

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue finally. Have to add our Kconfig path to the root Kconfig file. Like ---> source "drivers/xxx/Kconfig" in the root Kconfig file so that it allows the build to use the new driver Kconfig file.